# How to import a file from one package into another in Python without using sys.path.append(...) in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, package, relative-import

I am working on a Python project using Visual Studio Code (VSC) and have the following folder structure:

```
Python  
├──.vscode  
│   └── launch.json  
├── package1  
│   ├── __init__.py  
│   └── module1.py  
├── package2  
│   ├── __init__.py  
│   └── module2.py  
└── Python.code-workspace
```

I want to import module1.py from package1 into module2.py in package2. However, I'm facing difficulties getting the import statement to work correctly without using sys.path.append(...).

Here's the import statement I've tried in module2.py:
from package1 import module1

However, when I run the code, I receive an ImportError stating that the module cannot be found. I have verified that both packages have an __init__.py file.

I have also tried modifying the launch.json file in VSC to set the PYTHONPATH and avoid using sys.path.append(...), but the import still fails. Here's my current launch.json configuration:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python Launch",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/package2/module2.py",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/package2",
      "env": {
        "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to properly import a file from one package into another without relying on sys.path.append(...) and considering the project structure in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: The content of PYTHONPATH shows up in `sys.path`. Do you see what you expect there?

Comment: No, even though I have set the PYTHONPATH to "${workspaceFolder}", I expect my Python folder to be included in the sys.path. However, when I print sys.path, I do not see it listed.

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` and `PATH` are completely different env variables, check `PYTHONPATH` in the environment of the current process inside the `module2.py` script.

Comment: you can always set `PYTHONPATH` in the shell BEFORE you launch VSC

Comment: If I print this: `print(os.environ.get('PYTHONPATH'))`. It says `None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After configuring *launch.json*, you need to use the green triangle button to debug the script in the `Run and Debugging` panel or use `Start Debugging` or `Run Without Debugging` under the **Run** menu to debug or execute the script. The above method will use the configuration in *launch.json*.

[image]

If you use the upper right triangle button to execute the script, this will not load the configuration in *launch.json*.

[image]

The same file structure as yours, the effect of using **Run** --> `Run Without Debugging`.

[image]

*Using the display *launch.json* in your question can also run successfully.*

Another way is to add the `.env` file under the `python` folder

[image]

Then use **Run** --> `Run Without Debugging` to execute `moudle2.py`

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration `pwd` is the current working directory. Change it to : `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",` to be at the root of your project. After you can import your module.

Comment: How would you import a python file from a package you created?

Comment: from package1 import *